# DeadlineExceededError on using google client Api for BigQuery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-client

Trying to retrieve data from google big query data on a project.

```
query_response = query_request.query(projectId=PROJECTID, body=query_data).execute()
```

Nothing is wrong with the query except that whenever i make a call to it, i get

```
    The API call urlfetch.Fetch() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
DeadlineExceededError: The API call urlfetch.Fetch() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
```

I have referred to [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788851/how-to-set-deadline-for-bigquery-on-google-app-engine)

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)
```

in my code but still gets the error.

Comment: So that means the time taken is longer than your deadline (ie 60sec).  Reduce the amount of time either by reducing the complexity, or run the query in a task, and fetch the results later.  You should probably provide more context - how you a re running the query (e.g from a front end request) how much data, how long you expect the query to take.